# Hover Working On Other Div's Except The Middle Row One

Tags: html, css

I had added a CSS3 hover effect to my divs, and the hover effect is working on the first row and the last one, however, the effect isn't working in the middle row.

If I use Google Chrome's Inspect Element tab and enable the hover effect, the middle row hovers, but when I actually hover over it, it doesn't work.

Here's my code:-

```css
.itemFrame-1Wrap {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 18px;
}

.cat-name-1 {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #ff0000;
  font-family: lato-2;
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.itemFrame-1 {
  margin-left: 25px;
}

.itemFrame-1:hover {
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
  -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.itemname-cat1 {
  font-family: lato-2;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #ff0000;
}

.cat-1-line {
  width: 2px;
  height: 550px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  margin-left: 160px;
  position: absolute;
}

.itemimage {
}

.cat-1-line-end {
  width: 2px;
  height: 550px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  position: absolute;
}

/*Medium Rares Begins Here*/

.itemFrame-2Wrap {
  margin-left: 200px;
  position: absolute;
}

.cat-2-line {
  width: 2px;
  height: 550px;
  background-color: #ffcc00;
  margin-left: 170px;
  position: absolute;
}

.cat-name-2 {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #ffcc00;
  font-family: lato-2;
  margin-left: -15px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.itemFrame-2 {
  margin-left: 25px;
}

.itemFrame-2:hover {
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
  -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.itemname-cat2 {
  font-family: lato-2;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #ffcc00;
}

.cat-2-line-end {
  width: 2px;
  height: 550px;
  background-color: #ffcc00;
  margin-left: 340px;
  position: absolute;
}

/*Medium Rares Ends Here*/

/*Low Rares Begins Here*/

.itemFrame-3Wrap {
  margin-left: 200px;
  position: absolute;
}

.cat-3-line {
  width: 2px;
  height: 550px;
  background-color: #bfff00;
  margin-left: 350px;
  position: absolute;
}

.cat-name-3 {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #bfff00;
  font-family: lato-2;
  margin-left: 176px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.itemFrame-3 {
  margin-left: 205px;
}

.itemFrame-3:hover {
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
  -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.itemname-cat3 {
  font-family: lato-2;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #bfff00;
}

.cat-3-line-end {
  width: 2px;
  height: 550px;
  background-color: #bfff00;
  margin-left: 523px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>New Stick Run Item Ranking List</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/rankingDesignNew3.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="fullwrap">
    <!--CAT 1 BEGINS HERE-->
    <div class="cat-1-line"></div>
    <div class="itemFrame-1Wrap">
      <p class="cat-name-1">High Worth Rares</p>
      <div class="itemFrame-1">
        <img class="iteminner" src="static/images/red.png">
        <p class="itemname-cat1">Item Name</p>
      </div>

      <div class="itemFrame-1">
        <img class="iteminner" src="static/images/red.png">
        <p class="itemname-cat1">Item Name</p>
      </div>

      <div class="itemFrame-1">
        <img class="itemimage" src="static/images/red.png">
        <p class="itemname-cat1">Item Name</p>
      </div>

      <div class="itemFrame-1">
        <img class="iteminner" src="static/images/red.png">
        <p class="itemname-cat1">Item Name</p>
      </div>

      <div class="itemFrame-1">
        <img class="iteminner" src="static/images/red.png">
        <p class="itemname-cat1">Item Name</p>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cat-1-line-end"></div>
    <!-- CAT 1 ENDS HERE -->
    <!-- ++++ -->
    <!-- ++++ -->
    <!-- CAT 2 STARTS HERE -->
    <div class="cat-2-line"></div>
    <div class="itemFrame-2Wrap">
      <p class="cat-name-2">Medium Worth Rares</p>
      <div class="itemFrame-2">
        <img class="iteminner" src="static/images/red.png">
        <p class="itemname-cat2">Item Name</p>
      </div>

      <div class="itemFrame-2">
        <img class="iteminner" src="static/images/red.png">
        <p class="itemname-cat2">Item Name</p>
      </div>

      <div class="itemFrame-2">
        <img class="itemimage" src="static/images/red.png">
        <p class="itemname-cat2">Item Name</p>
      </div>

      <div class="itemFrame-2">
        <img class="iteminner" src="static/images/red.png">
        <p class="itemname-cat2">Item Name</p>
      </div>

      <div class="itemFrame-2">
        <img class="iteminner" src="static/images/red.png">
        <p class="itemname-cat2">Item Name</p>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cat-2-line-end"></div>
    <!-- CAT 2 ENDS HERE -->

    <!---------------------------DIVIDER------------------------------------------->

    <!--CAT 3 BEGINS HERE-->
    <div class="cat-3-line"></div>
    <div class="itemFrame-3Wrap">
      <p class="cat-name-3">Low Worth Rares</p>
      <div class="itemFrame-3">
        <img class="iteminner" src="static/images/red.png">
        <p class="itemname-cat3">Item Name</p>
      </div>

      <div class="itemFrame-3">
        <img class="iteminner" src="static/images/red.png">
        <p class="itemname-cat3">Item Name</p>
      </div>

      <div class="itemFrame-3">
        <img class="itemimage" src="static/images/red.png">
        <p class="itemname-cat3">Item Name</p>
      </div>

      <div class="itemFrame-3">
        <img class="iteminner" src="static/images/red.png">
        <p class="itemname-cat3">Item Name</p>
      </div>

      <div class="itemFrame-3">
        <img class="iteminner" src="static/images/red.png">
        <p class="itemname-cat3">Item Name</p>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cat-3-line-end"></div>
    <!-- CAT 3 ENDS HERE -->
    <!-- ++++ -->
    <!-- ++++ -->
  </div>
```

Comment: Just a second, please wait.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/4LKMB6KZ Am unable to post the HTML because of some error going on.

Answer (score 2):

I would remove all of your absolute positioning, and the `.cat-*-line*` classes, make the parent `display: flex` and use `border` on the `.itemFrame-*Wrap` elements for your left/right borders.

```css
.cat-name-1 {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #ff0000;
  font-family: lato-2;
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.itemFrame-1:hover {
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
  -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.itemname-cat1 {
  font-family: lato-2;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #ff0000;
}

.cat-1-line {
  width: 2px;
  height: 550px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

/*Medium Rares Begins Here*/

.cat-2-line {
  width: 2px;
  height: 550px;
  background-color: #ffcc00;
}

.cat-name-2 {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #ffcc00;
  font-family: lato-2;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.itemFrame-2:hover {
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
  -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.itemname-cat2 {
  font-family: lato-2;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #ffcc00;
}

/*Medium Rares Ends Here*/

/*Low Rares Begins Here*/

.cat-3-line {
  width: 2px;
  height: 550px;
  background-color: #bfff00;
}

.cat-name-3 {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #bfff00;
  font-family: lato-2;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.itemFrame-3:hover {
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
  -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.itemname-cat3 {
  font-family: lato-2;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #bfff00;
}


.fullwrap {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  margin-right: 8px;
  border: solid;
  border-width: 0 2px;
  height: 550px;
  padding: 0 18px;
}

.itemFrame-3Wrap {
  border-color: #bfff00;
}

.itemFrame-2Wrap {
  border-color: #ffcc00;
}

.itemFrame-1Wrap {
  border-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>New Stick Run Item Ranking List</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/rankingDesignNew3.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="fullwrap">
    <!--CAT 1 BEGINS HERE-->
    <div class="itemFrame-1Wrap item">
      <p class="cat-name-1">High Worth Rares</p>
      <div class="itemFrame-1">
        <img class="iteminner" src="static/images/red.png">
        <p class="itemname-cat1">Item Name</p>
      </div>

      <div class="itemFrame-1">
        <img class="iteminner" src="static/images/red.png">
        <p class="itemname-cat1">Item Name</p>
      </div>

      <div class="itemFrame-1">
        <img class="itemimage" src="static/images/red.png">
        <p class="itemname-cat1">Item Name</p>
      </div>

      <div class="itemFrame-1">
        <img class="iteminner" src="static/images/red.png">
        <p class="itemname-cat1">Item Name</p>
      </div>

      <div class="itemFrame-1">
        <img class="iteminner" src="static/images/red.png">
        <p class="itemname-cat1">Item Name</p>

      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- CAT 1 ENDS HERE -->
    <!-- ++++ -->
    <!-- ++++ -->
    <!-- CAT 2 STARTS HERE -->
    <div class="itemFrame-2Wrap item">
      <p class="cat-name-2">Medium Worth Rares</p>
      <div class="itemFrame-2">
        <img class="iteminner" src="static/images/red.png">
        <p class="itemname-cat2">Item Name</p>
      </div>

      <div class="itemFrame-2">
        <img class="iteminner" src="static/images/red.png">
        <p class="itemname-cat2">Item Name</p>
      </div>

      <div class="itemFrame-2">
        <img class="itemimage" src="static/images/red.png">
        <p class="itemname-cat2">Item Name</p>
      </div>

      <div class="itemFrame-2">
        <img class="iteminner" src="static/images/red.png">
        <p class="itemname-cat2">Item Name</p>
      </div>

      <div class="itemFrame-2">
        <img class="iteminner" src="static/images/red.png">
        <p class="itemname-cat2">Item Name</p>

      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- CAT 2 ENDS HERE -->

    <!---------------------------DIVIDER------------------------------------------->

    <!--CAT 3 BEGINS HERE-->
    <div class="itemFrame-3Wrap item">
      <p class="cat-name-3">Low Worth Rares</p>
      <div class="itemFrame-3">
        <img class="iteminner" src="static/images/red.png">
        <p class="itemname-cat3">Item Name</p>
      </div>

      <div class="itemFrame-3">
        <img class="iteminner" src="static/images/red.png">
        <p class="itemname-cat3">Item Name</p>
      </div>

      <div class="itemFrame-3">
        <img class="itemimage" src="static/images/red.png">
        <p class="itemname-cat3">Item Name</p>
      </div>

      <div class="itemFrame-3">
        <img class="iteminner" src="static/images/red.png">
        <p class="itemname-cat3">Item Name</p>
      </div>

      <div class="itemFrame-3">
        <img class="iteminner" src="static/images/red.png">
        <p class="itemname-cat3">Item Name</p>

      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- CAT 3 ENDS HERE -->
    <!-- ++++ -->
    <!-- ++++ -->
  </div>
```

Comment: Hey, this actually worked for me. Thanks a lot, Sir Michael!

Answer (score 0):

```css
   .itemFrame-1Wrap {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 18px;
}

.cat-name-1 {
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #ff0000;
    font-family: lato-2;
    margin-left: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.itemFrame-1 {
    margin-left: 25px;

}

.itemFrame-1:hover {
    z-index: 2;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
    -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
    transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

.itemname-cat1 {
    font-family: lato-2;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #ff0000;
}

.cat-1-line {
    width: 2px;
    height: 550px;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    margin-left: 160px;
    position: absolute;
}

.itemimage {
}

.cat-1-line-end {
    width: 2px;
    height: 550px;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    position: absolute;
}


/*Medium Rares Begins Here*/

.itemFrame-2Wrap {
    margin-left: 200px;
    position: absolute;
}

.cat-2-line {
    width: 2px;
    height: 550px;
    background-color: #ffcc00;
    margin-left: 170px;
    position: absolute;
}

.cat-name-2 {
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #ffcc00;
    font-family: lato-2;
    margin-left: -15px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.itemFrame-2 {
    margin-left: 25px;
}

.itemFrame-2:hover {
    z-index: 2;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
    -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
    transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

.itemname-cat2 {
    font-family: lato-2;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #ffcc00;
}

.cat-2-line-end {
    width: 2px;
    height: 550px;
    background-color: #ffcc00;
    margin-left: 340px;
    position: absolute;

}

/*Medium Rares Ends Here*/

/*Low Rares Begins Here*/

.itemFrame-3Wrap {
    margin-left: 200px;
    //position: absolute;
}

.cat-3-line {
    width: 2px;
    height: 550px;
    background-color: #bfff00;
    margin-left: 350px;
    position: absolute;
}

.cat-name-3 {
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #bfff00;
    font-family: lato-2;
    margin-left: 176px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.itemFrame-3 {
    margin-left: 205px;
}

.itemFrame-3:hover {
    z-index: 2;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
    -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
    transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

.itemname-cat3 {
    font-family: lato-2;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #bfff00;
}

.cat-3-line-end {
    width: 2px;
    height: 550px;
    background-color: #bfff00;
    margin-left: 523px;
    position: absolute;

}
```

```html
  <div class="fullwrap">
  <!--CAT 1 BEGINS HERE-->
  <div class="cat-1-line"></div>
  <div class="itemFrame-1Wrap">
  <p class="cat-name-1">High Worth Rares</p>  
  <div class="itemFrame-1">
    <img class="iteminner" src="static/images/red.png">
    <p class="itemname-cat1">Item Name</p>  
  </div>
  
    <div class="itemFrame-1">
    <img class="iteminner" src="static/images/red.png">
    <p class="itemname-cat1">Item Name</p>  
  </div>
  
    <div class="itemFrame-1">
    <img class="itemimage" src="static/images/red.png">
    <p class="itemname-cat1">Item Name</p>  
  </div>
  
    <div class="itemFrame-1">
    <img class="iteminner" src="static/images/red.png">
    <p class="itemname-cat1">Item Name</p>  
  </div>
  
    <div class="itemFrame-1">
    <img class="iteminner" src="static/images/red.png">
    <p class="itemname-cat1">Item Name</p>
    
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cat-1-line-end"></div>
  <!-- CAT 1 ENDS HERE -->
  <!-- ++++ -->
  <!-- ++++ -->
  <!-- CAT 2 STARTS HERE -->
    <div class="cat-2-line"></div>
  <div class="itemFrame-2Wrap">
  <p class="cat-name-2">Medium Worth Rares</p>  
  <div class="itemFrame-2">
    <img class="iteminner" src="static/images/red.png">
    <p class="itemname-cat2">Item Name</p>  
  </div>
  
    <div class="itemFrame-2">
    <img class="iteminner" src="static/images/red.png">
    <p class="itemname-cat2">Item Name</p>  
  </div>
  
    <div class="itemFrame-2">
    <img class="itemimage" src="static/images/red.png">
    <p class="itemname-cat2">Item Name</p>  
  </div>
  
    <div class="itemFrame-2">
    <img class="iteminner" src="static/images/red.png">
    <p class="itemname-cat2">Item Name</p>  
  </div>
  
    <div class="itemFrame-2">
    <img class="iteminner" src="static/images/red.png">
    <p class="itemname-cat2">Item Name</p>
    
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cat-2-line-end"></div>
  <!-- CAT 2 ENDS HERE -->
  
  <!---------------------------DIVIDER------------------------------------------->
  
    <!--CAT 3 BEGINS HERE-->
  <div class="cat-3-line"></div>
  <div class="itemFrame-3Wrap">
  <p class="cat-name-3">Low Worth Rares</p>  
  <div class="itemFrame-3">
    <img class="iteminner" src="static/images/red.png">
    <p class="itemname-cat3">Item Name</p>  
  </div>
  
    <div class="itemFrame-3">
    <img class="iteminner" src="static/images/red.png">
    <p class="itemname-cat3">Item Name</p>  
  </div>
  
    <div class="itemFrame-3">
    <img class="itemimage" src="static/images/red.png">
    <p class="itemname-cat3">Item Name</p>  
  </div>
  
    <div class="itemFrame-3">
    <img class="iteminner" src="static/images/red.png">
    <p class="itemname-cat3">Item Name</p>  
  </div>
  
    <div class="itemFrame-3">
    <img class="iteminner" src="static/images/red.png">
    <p class="itemname-cat3">Item Name</p>
    
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cat-3-line-end"></div>
  <!-- CAT 3 ENDS HERE -->
  <!-- ++++ -->
  <!-- ++++ -->
  </div>
```

I have removed `position:absolute` from `itemFrame-3Wrap` class. It works for me.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi there, thank you for helping me. However, when I make this change, the third last line and the hover gets a little disfigured. Pic: http://prntscr.com/fnbwht

Any solution? Thanks!

Comment: that's because you have given `position:absolute` . Is it required in your code ?

Comment: I want it to look like the first two rows. The third last line has gone down, and when I hover over the third row's image, it moves a little too much.

Comment: I had added position:absolute; to ".itemFrame-3Wrap" so that the page looks like this:- http://prntscr.com/fnc08l . But when I do this, the middle row stops working.

However, if I remove it, the last line (.cat-3-line-end) goes down, and the hover effect moves too much.

What I want to see to it is that the whole page looks like this: http://prntscr.com/fnc08l with the middle row hover effect working.